# Running MPI on windows using minGW64 through Msys2

Tags: mpi, mingw-w64, msys2

I've just installed the package for mpi using msys2:
`pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-msmpi`

I've noticed that this has installed some executables to compile the code such as mpicc.exe, but I can't find anything to run it. Am I missing something or MPI is just poorly supported by msys2 and minGW? Seems a little odd that there's a compiler but not a dedicated runner since MPI is designed to parallelize a program and to be able to run multiple executions is a key factor in the library/technology